# Batch file: take values from two different text files, export with text string to new file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Contents of **File A**:

```
TaskName:                             \Microsoft\Windows\Work Folders\Work Folders Maintenance Work
TaskName:                             \Microsoft\Windows\Workplace Join\Automatic-Device-Join
TaskName:                             \Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask
TaskName:                             \Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTaskLogon
```

Contents of **File B**:

```
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Scheduled Task State:                 Disabled
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
```

**In File B** I would like to replace "Enabled" with "Enable" and "Disabled" with "Disable," as follows:

```
Scheduled Task State:                 Enable
Scheduled Task State:                 Disable
Scheduled Task State:                 Enable
Scheduled Task State:                 Enable
```

Lastly, I would like to take the values of File A and File B and export the following string to **File C**:

```
:: String format: schtasks /change /TN "FILE-A_VALUE in quotes" /FILE-B_VALUE

schtasks /change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Work Folders\Work Folders Maintenance Work" /Enable
schtasks /change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Workplace Join\Automatic-Device-Join" /Disable
schtasks /change /TN "\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask" /Enable
schtasks /change /TN "\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTaskLogon" /Enable
```

Is this possible from a batch file? Thanks for any and all help.

UPDATE:

Below is the full list of commands used create the files in this process, incorporating the answer by user Stephan:

```
:: Complete commands to back up the current enabled/disabled state of all Windows scheduled tasks to a batch file; the outputted batch file will be in the form of schtasks commands to restore the enabled/disabled states. Note: all scheduled task values are language-dependent; as such the processes below are for English only.     

:: Get list and parameters of all tasks; find values for TaskName, which includes full path and name of each scheduled tasks; save values to temp File A.

    SCHTASKS /Query /FO LIST /v| findstr /r /C:"TaskName: " >fileA.txt

:: Re-get list and parameters of all tasks; find values for Scheduled Task State; save values to temp File B

    SCHTASKS /Query /FO LIST /v| findstr /r /C:"Scheduled Task State: " >fileB.txt

:: Read both files in parallel using delayed expansion to set variables from both files

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<fileB.txt (

:: Set variable for task name from fileA
for /f "delims=" %%a in (fileA.txt) do (
    set "task=%%a"
    set "task=!task:~38!
    set /p "line="

:: Set variable for task state from fileB, and truncate line so values are changed from enabled/disabled to enable/disable    
for %%A in ("!line:~38,-1!") do set "state=%%~A"

:: output task name and truncated task state in the local language needed for schtasks command to enable/disable tasks
:: Example: schtasks /change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client\AD RMS Rights Policy Template Management (Automated)" /Disable     
echo schtasks /change /TN "!task!" /!state!
  )
) >fileC.bat
```

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes!

Comment: Thanks Aacini. I should have been more specific :)

Comment: @pazdel: *way* more specific. As your question looks now, it's just a "write my code" request, which is likely to be downvoted and/or closed. Well, at least you showed some effort to create the logic, that's why I bothered to answer.

Comment: @Stephan: I appreciate the guidance. I was in way over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little trick to read two files in parallel:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<fileB.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (fileA.txt) do (
    set "task=%%a"
    set "task=!task:~38!
    set /p "line="
    for %%A in ("!line:~38,-1!") do set "state=%%~A"
    echo schtasks /change /TN "!task!" /!state!
  )
) >fileC.bat
```

Notes: there is a risk to read task name and task status in two steps: a task might get deleted or added between those steps, which will lead to non-synchronous lists.
Also `schtasks` output is language dependent.
Also I doubt, if `:~38` is reliable on all systems.
The code above works with your example files.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan. This worked for me. Files A and B will be created just before merging their values, so the lists becoming non-synchronous should be minimal. I am also not too happy about my method being language dependent (as you pointed out earlier as well), but I am not aware of any other way to get to this result (so many limitations to the schtasks command, importing of tasks via xml, etc.). To avoid potential issues with truncating the lines in File B (:~38), is it possible to replace word-for-word instead, e.g., "enable" for "enabled" and "disable" for "disabled"?

Comment: PS - Assuming no change in language, what might be the factors in :~38 not being reliable on different systems?

Comment: [set](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) can replace strings. PS: output is language specific, that means, titles may have different length. `/FO list` formats according to the max. length. (see `schtasks /query  /fo list` vs. `schtasks /query  /fo list /v`: different column widths