# How to iterate through FOR IN outputs with IF statements in Windows Batch?

Tags: batch-file, sha256, certutil

I have a directory of files, a `HashControlFile.txt` which contains the SHA256 sum calculated from the files in the directory, and a need to iterate through these files in a way that calculates and formats the output from the `CertUtil` utility in Windows and checks between the directory files and the HashControlFile and provides a framework for performing additional action whether a match was found or not between them.

The `HashControlFile.txt` only contains SHA256sum entries, a new one each line, such as:

```
181210f8f9c779c26da1d9b2075bde0127302ee0e3fca38c9a83f5b1dd8e5d3b
```

for a file who's contents are simply `123`.

I have two elements of this puzzle already. To loop through the directory any produce a SHA256sum the below produces such in a way that formats it to prevent hex pairings that can occur between different versions of the `CertUtil.exe` on Windows:

```bash
for  %%i in (\\FileDirectory\*) do (
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -HashFile "%%i" SHA256 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ":"') Do @Set "hash=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%H In ("!hash: =!") Do @EndLocal & Echo(%%~H) >> \\OtherDirectory\HashControlFile.txt
)
```

Additionally, to loop through the directory and compare the between the files and HashControlFile I have the below piece:

```bash
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (\\FileDirectory\*) DO (
 FOR /f %%y IN (####Produce FORMATTED SHA256SUM HERE####) do (
  findstr /x "%%y" \\OtherDirectory\HashControlFile.txt > NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO "%%b" NOT found
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO "%%b" found
  )
 )
)
```

My difficulty has been in using the above element within the second element to loop through using formatted CertUtil output. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43862228/2152082) is helpful? (just replace the "second file" with `####Produce FORMATTED SHA256SUM HERE####`) Although it will only work if the filenames are the very same in both instances (no missing/additional files). Also, it probably won't work on FAT file systems (unsorted filenames)

Comment: It is perfectly feasible that more than one file, with different names, or even any/same name but a different location, can have exactly the same content, and therefore the same hash. Whilst it may be simpler to have a file containing just a hash, the only way I see this type of thing being useful is if it contained both the fully qualified absolute filename along side its hash, (preferably separated by a pipe or other character disallowed in Windows file or directory names).

Comment: It is also important to remember that `certutil.exe` is limited with respect to the maximum file size it can handle.

Comment: @Compo for the purposes of this script the need to qualify between the file names and contents are not important. The use case here is to only verify between whether the contents of the files within the directory match the given list of contents within the HashControlLFile. I do take your point noting that this may produce erroneous instances where the multiple files are matched regardless of filename. That distinction isn't a vital element here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA256 hash lookup for each file in a directory in a file containing only SHA256 hash values can be done with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Directory=\\ServerName\ShareName\FilesDirectory"
set "HashFile=\\ServerName\ShareName\OtherDirectory\HashControlFile.txt"
if not exist "%HashFile%" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%HashFile%"& goto EndBatch
for %%G in ("%Directory%\*") do if /I not "%%G" == "%HashFile%" if not "%%G" == "%~f0" (
    set "FileName=%%~nxG"
    for /F "delims=" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\certutil.exe -HashFile "%%G" SHA256 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ":"') do (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "HashValue=%%H"
        %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /X /C:"!HashValue: =!" "!HashFile!" >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo   FOUND: "!FileName!"
        ) else (
            echo MISSING: "!FileName!"
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The environment variable `Directory` is defined with the directory containing the files of which SHA256 hash values should be determined and looked up in the file with the hash values.

The environment variable `HashFile` is defined with the fully qualified file name of the ASCII/ANSI encoded text file containing all the SHA256 hash values.

Then is checked the existence of the file with the hash values. An error message is output and nothing else is done if the specified hash list file does not exist at all. See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&` which is used in the command line with the first **IF** condition.

The most outer **FOR** loop processes all non-hidden files in specified directory.

The second **IF** condition with a **case-insensitive** string comparison is for ignoring the file with the hash values if this file is in the same directory as the files to process which is not the case with the paths specified in the code above, but is in general possible.

The third **IF** condition with a *case-sensitive* string comparison is for ignoring the batch file if the currently processed batch file is in the directory of the files to process.

The name of the file with file extension but without path of the current file is assigned to the environment variable `FileName`. Delayed variable expansion is disabled on execution of this command line and the next command line resulting in entire batch file working also for files with one or more exclamation mark in fully qualified file name.

The inner **FOR** loop runs in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified within `'` appended as additional arguments.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>NUL` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The SHA256 hash value of the file is assigned to the loop variable `H` which is in format:

```
18 12 10 f8 f9 c7 79 c2 6d a1 d9 b2 07 5b de 01 27 30 2e e0 e3 fc a3 8c 9a 83 f5 b1 dd 8e 5d 3b
```

The spaces must be removed to get the SHA256 hash value to look up in the file with all the hash values.

Delayed variable expansion is enabled now before assigning the hash value with the spaces to an environment variable with name `HashValue`.

Next is executed **FINDSTR** to search in the file with all the hash values literally and *case-sensitive* for a line which matches **completely** with the current hash value with all spaces removed using a delayed expanded variable reference with substitution of every space character by an empty string, i.e. removal of all spaces from the hash value. There is of no interest of the found line(s) if the hash value is found at all in the hash list file which is the reason for redirecting the output of **FINDSTR** to device **NUL** to suppress the output of the found line(s). There is only of interest if the hash value is found or not found by **FINDSTR** in the hash list file.

**FINDSTR** exits with exit code `1` if there is no match and with exit code `0` if there is at least one match. The exit code is assigned by `cmd.exe` to its internal dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL`. This exit code is evaluated for being less than 1 which means 0 to output the `FOUND:` or the `MISSING:` message with the current file name.

Then the previous execution environment is restored with an again disabled delayed variable expansion. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** as there is much more done on each iteration of the inner **FOR** loop in the background by `cmd.exe` than just changing the status of delayed variable expansion.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `certutil /?` or `certutil -?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you for not only the code but the expert explanation of Batch operators and design elements. By far one of the most informative answers I've seen on this site. You are a scholar and a gentleman, thank you.